# How to download gtk+-bundle_2.24.10 for win 64?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtk2

I used gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win32. Now I want to use gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win64. But I can't download it.

What ideas on how to solve this task would you suggest? Or on what resource on the internet can I find help?

Comment: What means `But I can't download it.`?

Comment: @Jens: I can't finde "gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win64 " on the internet to download it. If it possible help me to fine it. or another version for win64 up to 2.24.

Answer (score 2):

The GTK+ project does not provide pre-built archives for Windows any more.

GTK+ 2.24.10 is also a *very* old version of GTK+ 2.x, released in 2012; the current release for GTK+ 2.x is 2.24.30, released March 2016. The latest GTK+ 2.24 release also contains various Windows build and functionality fixes, so it's **strongly** recommended that you use it if you're shipping on Windows.

The recommended way to get a GTK+ build on Windows is to use [MSYS2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/); once you've built your application and its dependencies, you can take the resulting build artifacts and provide them to your users, using an auto-extracting zip file, or an installer.